# Масштабирования изображения в VideoView

Tags: android, videoview

Как масштабировать видео в *VideoView*?

По запросу получаю *hls*-ссылку на трансляцию. Видео приходят в разрешениях (4:3,16:9).

Загвоздка в том, что я не могу получить размер кадра, чтобы изменить *VideoView*. Прочитав документацию, нашел метод `setVideoScalingMode()` - не подходит, так как должно запускаться на *API 14 (4.0)*.

Известны ли вам решения этой проблемы или как я могу получить размер видео?

Comment: а как вы пытались получать размер кадра?

Comment: 1.Писал свою видео ВидеоВиьюв и переопределял метод onMeasure();
2. Растягивая по всему родительскому контейнеру или центрирую  по нему пытался получить размер контейнера и через него преобразовать видео;
3. Назначил слушателей OnPreparedListener, OnVideoSizeCahngeListener - у обоих входным параметром является MediaPlayer. Пытался его значения получить, но они зависят от контейнера. 
Посмотрев в других приложениях заметил что у них окно проигрывания фиксированной высоты,а вот ширина изменяется для корректного изображения, сейчас пытаюсь через макет добиться такого эффекта.

Comment: `MediaPlayer.getVideoWidth();` `MediaPlayer.getVideoHeight();` пробовали?

Comment: Так точно. Возвращает такой же результат как и .VideoView.getMeasuredWidth();VideoVIew.getMeasuredHeight(); VideoView.getWidth();VideoVIew.getHeight().     Есть подозрения что трансляции имеют разные пропорции, а видео приходит одного разрешения(уже искаженные - а получить размер частички изображения еще трудней).